# MVC3 jquery ajax json data

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to parse the json retrieved from a webservice called from my controller.
For now, just to show the json string, I've done this

```
        $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { myPartNo: returnVal },
        success: function (result) { 
            ShowJson(result);
        }
    });
```

I just have the json string data displayed in a div as text (it works) but basically, I just want a few of the values from that json like "color" and "size" for example.  Ok, so the vocabulary words like object array deserialize etc is where I need help.  I've probably done it in other projects without knowing what it is called.  What do I need to do?  From the controller end or just within javascript?

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you usually define some DTO (data transfer object) that has everything inside like:

```
public class MyDTO
{
public string value {get; set;}
public string color {get; set;}
public int size {get; set;}
}
```

In your controller you just wrap it into Json:

```
ActionResult MyController(int whatever)
{
MyDTO model = new MyDTO();
model.value = ...
return this.Json(model);
}
```

On the client side you read the result and treat it as a regular object like:

```
ShowJson(result.color);
```

//or

```
$("#mydiv").css("color", result.color); // for example
```

Comment: thank you Kate for the post.  You know where you have the "..." part in result.value, that's the webservice which response is a json string that I do not know the syntax for.  Or would I use jQuery.parseJSON on the view?

Comment: It's only about server side. Sorry for confusing, it was only about model. You just define the value and then pass as Json result. Let me know if it's still unclear.